# Set from address text in bash mail

Tags: email, sendmail

I am able to send mail from bash, but cannot change the from text, it currently comes up as 'root'.

I would like email clients to show the following text in the from field `script on myserver.com (root@myserver.com)`.

How can I do this please?

```
emailsubject="$scriptname ($scriptver) log at $startdate"

if [ $errorcount > 0 ]; then
    emailsubject="ERRORS($errorcount) - ${emailsubject}"
fi

mail -s "$emailsubject" tobealerted@hotmail.com < $logfile
```

Comment: `[ $errorcount > 0 ]` should be `[ $errorcount -gt 0 ]` (see `man test`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a BASH issue. This is an issue with the mail program itself.

Run the command `man mail` and see the options for the command. It varies from system to system. Check for a parameter that allows you to set who the mail is from or the sender. If `mail` doesn't have such a parameter, try `mailx` which has more options. (It looks like your system has `mailx` called `mail`.

On my system, I use `mailx` instead of `mail` and I can use the `-r` parameter to set a *sender address*:

```
mailx -r president@whitehouse.gov -s "Secret Message. For your eyes only" < $file
```

Answer (score 13):

If Your "mail" supports it, You may add custom headers using the -a switch like this:

```
mail -s "subject" -a "From: president@whitehouse.gov" ...
```

Comment: `-a file           Attach the given file to the message.`

Comment: @Roman Hocke on my debian its actually: `-a, --append=HEADER: VALUE` and `-A, --attach=FILE`